# Loopback Controller APIs not working inside electron app

Tags: electron, loopbackjs, electron-packager

I am trying to run a loopback based application inside by electron app. I was successful in configuring SQLite into loopback and also DB migration inside the app. The server runs fine inside electron in debug mode and I am able to access API endpoints that I created. But when I package the app and run the `.app` file, the server starts up fine but there are no API endpoints. Here is the link to code: https://github.com/sahilanguralla/daakiya

Comment: i think the issue you are having is you are loading things by path. you need to think things get packed in a .asar file meaning ../dll will not be there if its not part of your packed solution in production environments

Comment: @Kanekotic I am new to electron. Can you guide me a little bit?